# how to store a custom DATETIME format to Mysql DATETIME field

Tags: mysql, datetime

I want to store a `jalali` datetime to Mysql `DATETIME` field, for example, i store `1400-06-20 12:00:00` without any problem, but when i try to store `1400-06-31 12:00:00` Mysql says `Incorrect format` because month 6 has no 31th day in gregorian calendar. but in `jalali` calendar month 6 has 31th day. 
Is there any way to avoid Mysql checking for months and days of `DATETIME` format so that i can store DATETIME even when input datetime is out of gregorian calendar standard?

Comment: Convert the incoming Jalali date to Gregorian before you insert.

Comment: You can find answer in this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668683/storing-non-gregorian-dates-in-mysqls-date-type